# flash pro to flash builder migration of documentclass

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I am migrating a bunch of projects which were built in Flash Pro to Flash Builder....

The basic structure of those projects were an FLA which has a DocumentClass. That DocumentClass referenced various items on the stage...

Is there any way to duplicate this in Flash Builder? I know I can just embed the swc or swf and then access items via ThatDisplayObject.itemToAccess, but calls from outside will no longer work. I.e. if this project is loaded by a container, which then calls SubProject.itemToAccess...

Or must I change all the mappings, or set getters/settings on the new Flash Builder project so that outside calls will access the items?

Comment: Are you trying to migrate from Pure ActionScript to Flex?  Or Just wanting to use Flash Builder to write code now?  Based on some quick Googling; it sounds like the DocumentClass is just a Singleton accessible everywhere.  In a Flex App, the main application is kind of like the DocumentClass.  If you search you can find methods for creating Singletons in AS3.

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible (but it depends on how your Flash project is organised) to simply set the Document Class file to the default application in the Flash Builder project.
In your Flash project's Publish Settings check the "export as swc" option, and make sure the location where it publishes the swc is added to your FlashBuilder project's library path.

Hope this helps a bit. There may be more issues but these are the basics I think.